# Closed connection issues after DB upgrade from 11G to 19C & ojdbc14 to ojdbc8

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, ojdbc, oracle19c

I managed to successfully perform a DB upgrade from 11G to 19C & ojdbc14 to ojdbc8. However my application is now facing closed connection issues, java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection for almost all my queries after every few days. This issue usually go away after I perform a server restart. I am running my application on JBOSS WildFly 13.

I noticed this usually occurs when i ran this query, and there are around 170 records. However most of the Status are inactive. I am thinking this could be a out of resource memory issue. Instead of doing a server restart every few days, how am I supposed to fix this issue to remove the inactive status completely? Could this be a leak within my Java application, I have made very minimal code changes to the aplication except for some autocommit changes which were causing errors..

```
   select
   substr(a.spid,1,9) pid,
   substr(b.sid,1,5) sid,
   substr(b.serial#,1,5) ser#,
   substr(b.machine,1,6) box,
   substr(b.username,1,10) username,
   substr(b.osuser,1,8) os_user,
   substr(b.program,1,30) program,
   status
   from v$session b, v$process a
   where
   b.paddr = a.addr
   and type='USER'
   order by spid;
```

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-database_connection_validation moght help

Comment: Which connection cache/pool are you using?

Comment: any hints in the databases alertlog file? Do you have dead client detection enabled?